# Assembly code modification

Tags: assembly

I have an excersise that it appears in screen a predefined text you entered. I done that correctly. The program is the following:

```
 .model small
.stack
msg_len equ 37 
.data

my_msg db "READ THE LETTERS: A, B, C, D, E, F, G"
.code
start: 

mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov cx, msg_len
mov ah, 02h    

mov si, offset my_msg   


prntchar:
mov dl, byte ptr[si]
int 21h
inc si
loop prntchar
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h                 


mov dl, 0dh
int 21h
mov dl, 0ah
int 21h       

end start
```

After the programs finish I want to change the line and then press a character. For example D, and the program runs again and shows on screen the same text till the letter D. Hope you understand what I need. Thank you

Comment: What OS are you using? If on Windows: Are you allowed to use WinAPI?

Comment: I am using Windows and I run it with emu8086

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this **pdf**](http://www.philadelphia.edu.jo/academics/qhamarsheh/uploads/Lecture%2021%20MS-DOS%20Function%20Calls%20_INT%2021h_.pdf). You will find a few examples for the **[DOS int 21h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html)** and its function codes there.

What you are looking for will look like something like this:

```
.data
char BYTE ?
.code
L1: mov ah,06h   ; keyboard input
    mov dl,0FFh  ; don't wait for input
    int 21h
    jz L1        ; no character? repeat loop

    ; ...
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try and let you know

Comment: unfortunatelly it did not work but I figured it out. Thank you for your time though :-)